# Can a cordapp connect to 2 different schemas?

Tags: corda

Is it possible to use the node.conf to set up the connection for corda default tables and in my application I set up a connection for my business table?

For corporate reasons I need to keep the product(Corda) and business tables in different schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. The node is backed by a standard SQL database, and you are free to connect to this database (e.g. via JDBC) and create or modify other tables.